# Probability that random vectors have a certain dot product

Tags: probability, geometry

Given two random unit vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, one can consider the probability that the absolute value of their dot product is $x$, and thus form a probability density function. Supposing that the random vectors were drawn from a uniform distribution with respect to the surface of the sphere that they live in, **what is the probability that two vectors will have dot product less than $T$?**

My intuition is that this should be proportional to the surface area of the "cap" of the cone containing all angles less than $\arccos(T)$. But how to compute this?

Extra question: if we choose the vectors by drawing each component of each vector from a mean zero, unit variance Gaussian distribution, does the answer change?

Comment: You talk about these vectors living on a sphere.  Are these random *unit* vectors?

Comment: Yes, random unit vectors. Let me edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick two unit vectors.  Rotate your coordinate system so that one of them points at $(1,0,\ldots,0)$.  You want the probability that $x \cdot (1,0,\ldots, 0) < T$.  It will suffice to find the proportion of the surface area of the $n$-sphere not within an angle of $\cos^{-1}(T)$ from the North pole.

There are some nice formulas for the area of spherical caps in [this paper](http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/ansinet/ajms/0000/22275-22275.pdf) by S. Li.  In particular, the area of a cap with angle $\phi \leq \pi/2$ is $$A_n^{cap} = \frac{2\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})} \int_0^\phi \sin^{n-2}(\theta)d\theta.$$

On the other hand, the surface area of the $n$-sphere is [known to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area) $$\frac{2\pi^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}$$

Taking the quotient of these two, you'll get the proportion of there sphere within an angle of $\phi$ from the north pole.  Now subtract that from $1$ for your answer.

Comment: The upper index of your integral should be $\pi/2$, I think.

Comment: @EricGregor So that the angle $\phi$ does not appear in the formula?

Comment: er, what i mean is that you are integrating with respect to the variable in the upper index. you need to make one of those variables different.

Comment: Thank you. I've changed the variable off integration.